# How to associate getJSON error handler with query that caused it

Tags: jquery, error-handling, getjson

I'm doing a batch of getJSON() calls within a loop.

When the calls succeed the JSON returned contains a value equal to the loop counter, but when the error handler is called I can't seem to figure out a way to to find out which query caused it (which value the loop counter had for the failed call).

```
var p;
for (p = 1; p <= pagecount; p++) {
  var params = {
    page:     p,
    pagesize: 100
  };

  $.getJSON("http://api.travel.stackexchange.com/1.1/tags?jsonp=?",
    params,
    function(data) {
      /* I can use data.page to know the value of page in the query */
    }
  ).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    /* how can I find the value "page" had in the query? */
  });
}
```

Comment: Just so you're clear: you can only access `data.page` in the success callback because **it's part of the returned JSON.**

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL: Yes that's correct. But there should be a way to get it also via a closure, context, this, or maybe something that works with .ajax() but not with .getJSON() from browsing similar questions but so far with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a closure for each error callback:

```
function errorHandler(page) {
    return function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(page); // it works
    };
}

for (var p = 1; p <= pagecount; p++) {
    var params = {
        page: p,
        pagesize: 100
    };

    $.getJSON("http://api.travel.stackexchange.com/1.1/tags?jsonp=?",
              params,
              function(data) {

    }).error(errorHandler(p));
}
```

Comment: This is certainly easier to grok than David's answer but I'd like to understand both. Testing now on my real code...

Comment: This works but I can't get my head around why I can use `p` in `errorHandler(p)` but can't use it directly there.

Comment: @hippie: note that the code does not say `.error(errorHandler)`. what happens here is that `errorHandler` is called when the `getJSON` request is *initiated*, not when an actual error happens. When an error happens, the function *returned* by `errorHandler` will be called. Since `p` is passed to `errorHandler` when the call is *made*, it will have a different value for each iteration. Now, this different value will comprise part of the context in which the `error` callback is called.

Comment: @MДΓΓ: your inner function in `errorHandler` should access `page`, not `p`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a closure for `params` in each iteration:

```
var p;
for (p = 1; p <= pagecount; p++) {
  var x = {
    page:     p,
    pagesize: 100
  };

  (function(params) {
     return function() {
        $.getJSON("http://api.travel.stackexchange.com/1.1/tags?jsonp=?",
          params,
          function(data) {
            /* I can use data.page to know the value of page in the query */
          }
        ).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          /* how can I find the value "page" had in the query? */
        });
     };
  })(x);

}
```

Another solution would be to switch from `getJSON` to `ajax()`, that has the `context` property, which you could set to `params`. In that case, you'd be able to access the `params` object as `this` in your error callback.

```
context: params,
error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
    alert(this.pagesize);
}
```

Comment: I've seen this syntax used on a similar question using .ajax() but it's so hard to grok with all that dangling `})(x);` that I couldn't figure out how to adapt it to the .getJSON() case )-:

Comment: @hippie: well all that does is return a new function, where a new closure has been created for each instance of your `params` object. Do play around with that, it's immensely useful. But I've updated my answer with another approach which you might find more useful.

Comment: Aha yes I had read about the `context / this` approach in a similar question and wondered that it might not be usable from .getJSON() like it is from .ajax()

Comment: @hippie: there's nothing to keep you from switching to `ajax` though. You can still do JSONP requests. `getJSON` is just shorthand for one of the most common configurations of `ajax`.

Comment: Yes I just didn't want to switch to `.ajax()` until I fully understood the problem with `.getJSON()` - thanks.

Comment: Actually I can't get the first of your solutions to work at all. The .getJSON never gets called.

Comment: Uh, you're right, sorry about that. My code just returns a function that is never invoked. You'd have to append another `()`, so that the last line of that closure is `})(x)();`. But that just looks rather messy, doesn't it? It could be refactored into named variables for readability. Still, MДΓΓ's solution seems preferable.

Comment: I've learned that this type of JavaScript can lead to an entirely new class of spaghetti code that is almost impossible to read if you didn't write it - on a level that can compete even with Perl! (-:

Answer (score 2):

Switch to $.ajax instead, and add a property to the jqXHR object in a beforeSend handler:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://api.travel.stackexchange.com/1.1/tags?jsonp=?",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    data : params,
    success : your_success_function,
    error : your_error_function,
    beforeSend : function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.originalData = params;
    }
});
```

Then you can access the data via `jqXHR.originalData` in the error handler.

Comment: +1 if switching to `ajax`, I like this better than my `context` option.

Comment: This is not necessary anymore.